# select columns with different conditions

Tags: mysql, query

*This question focus to the COUNT result*

1st query will show the COUNT with date condition.

2nd query will show the COUNT without date condition.

Now I need a query which make the COUNT result in 1st query without date condition which is :
COUNT(c.CustomerID) > ONLY with condition b.BookingCustomerID=c.CustomerID
(without date condition)

c.CustomerTelephone, b.* > with condition WHERE b.BookingCustomerID=c.CustomerID
AND BookingDate LIKE '%2019-05-04%'

Thanks.

```
SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID), c.CustomerTelephone, b.*
FROM Booking b, Customer c 
WHERE b.BookingCustomerID=c.CustomerID
AND BookingDate LIKE '%2019-05-04%' 
GROUP BY c.CustomerID


SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID), c.CustomerTelephone, b.*
FROM Booking b, Customer c  
WHERE b.BookingCustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing a `GROUP BY`, it is improper to list anything other than the group-by columns and aggregates in the `SELECT` part.  In your case, the values of b.* could be random.

Are you trying to compute both counts at the same time?  If `BookingDate is in`c`, then it is easy.  If it is in the other table, then it gets messier.  _When`JOINing`, please make it clear which columns come from which tables._

```
SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID) AS count_all,
       SUM(( SELECT BookingDate FROM Booking
                     WHERE BookingCustomerID = c.CustomerID
                       AND BookingDate LIKE '2019-05-04%' )) AS count_day
    FROM Customer AS c
    GROUP BY c.CustomerId
```

To get the rest them,

```
SELECT x.count_all, x.count_day
       c.CustomerTelephone,
       b.*
    FROM ( ... the query above ... ) AS x
    JOIN Customer AS c USING(CustomerID)
    JOIN Booking AS b ON b.BookingCustomerID = x.CustomerID
    FROM Customer AS c
    GROUP BY c.CustomerId
```

Answer (score -1):

How its possible to "group by" a column with same with "count" . In your case you group by with customerId and also COUNT with customerId.

Can you please change group by Condition. on which basis(column) you want to COUNT by customerId.

Comment: you can try out ..following query..
select cnt,y.*
from 
(
SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID) cnt,BookingID
FROM Booking b, Customer c 
WHERE b.BookingCustomerID=c.CustomerID
GROUP BY BookingID
) as x
inner join (
SELECT c.CustomerTelephone, b.*
FROM Booking b, Customer c  
WHERE b.BookingCustomerID = c.CustomerID
AND BookingDate LIKE '%2019-05-04%'
) as y on z.BookingID =y.BookingID